# How to get newest one of friend's wall at once with FQL

Tags: javascript, stream, facebook-fql

I want to get newest one of friend's wall at once with FQL.

When I call following FQL, I cannot get every friend's wall.

```
'SELECT created_time,message FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())'
```

So, I call Graph API every friend's ID.

```
FB.api('/'+<friend uid>+'/posts?limit=1');
```

But, If a user have 5000 friends, it needs 5000 call.

Actually, it becomes the error on the way when I practice it.

Because even 50 cases are good, is not there the method to acquire?

Answer (score 0):

looks for fql batch you can execute up to 50 query at once

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!

I already tried batch request. 
Facebook API has restriction of the number of API call. It is 600 call per 600 seconds. So I called API every 1 second interval.
This method requires time. I am looking for the method which can be managed in as short time as possible.

Comment: we are bound to Facebook api ... Facebook doc states  fql batch is their way to optimize query